# Dereference a double pointer (a pointer to a pointer to a value) in GDB

Tags: c++, pointers, gdb

I'm writing a script to reverse engineer an executable. I have a situation where RAX is a pointer to a value which itself is a pointer to an object. The very first value of that object, in turn, is a pointer to a string. A visualization should clear it up:

```
RAX
 |
 | points to
 |
 V
Value on the stack
 |
 | points to
 |
 V
The start of an object (std::vector<std::string)
 |
 | the very first value of that object points to
 |
 V
A string in memory
```

I want to access the string in memory. How do I do that with one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
# Dereference RAX to get the value on the stack
(gdb) x/gx $rax         
0x7fffffffe0d0: 0x0000555555598700  

# Dereference the value on the stack to get the start of the object                        
(gdb) x/gx *((uint64_t*)$rax)            
0x555555598700: 0x0000555555578ea0    

# Dereference the start of the object because it points to a string
(gdb) x/s *((uint64_t*)*((uint64_t*)$rax))
0x555555578ea0: "/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

I had to cast the values to `uint64_t` because otherwise GDB would think it's a 32-bit value (I'm working with a 64-bit executable).

Additionally, there was another pointer to a string 4 bytes after the start of the vector object. Here's how I accessed that string:

```
x/s *((uint64_t*)*((uint64_t*)$rax) + 4)
```